# Separating my VPN connection from my internet access

Tags: vpn, routing

Background:
Home PC is Windows XP and using Cisco VPN client; home internet connection is fast (20MB)
office VPN router is Cisco RV110W; work internet connection is slow (1.5MB)

With VPN connected, my home PC internet surfing is very slow. I looked this up in Google and found talk about splitting, tunneling, routing tables, etc., but I'm not sure what/how to do it. Basically, I would like a persistent VPN connection with the office resources, and at the same time, utilize my home high speed internet connection to access the internet.

Can someone help me the steps as how-to?

Answer (score 1):

This won't be a fully detailed answer, but hopefully It will help you to solve your problem.

First you should check what is the status of the "Enable split-horizon" flag on your configuration. This setting is defined on the Cisco server, and your client got this information during the login procedure. (you can find it somewhere in the settings menu) If this flag is checked, theoretically you won't be able to separate your communication channels. ... in practically: instead of the Cisco VPN Client, start using ShrewVPN. This program doesn't (maybe can't?) handle the split-horizon flag. That was the tricky part.

From now, you are able to rewrite the routing definition on your computer. If you know the IPs/hostnames of your company-related resources, you only have to add manually a few routing record. Here is an example (works on windows) with comments:

route add 195.111.112.13 mask 255.255.255.255 123.122.17.198 metric 1
// 195.111.112.13: an example company IP
// 255.255.255.255: if you are not intrested in sysadmin things (me neither), the only thing you should know about this number, that it defines exact match to the previous IP
// 123.122.17.198: default gateway (where to route the traffic), the appropriate IP can be found in the output of the ipconfig command after you have connected to the VPN.
// metric 1: technically the "priority" of this rule

And your recipe based on the previous example:
route your company traffic (with separate route records and exact matches) through the VPN default gateway with metric 1
route anything else (random IP with 0.0.0.0 mask) through your original default gateway with metric 2